# Spark Add the Data to Result

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am writing the Streaming Kafka Result here is my code :

```py
StreamingQuery ds = result \
  .select(to_json(struct( METRIC_COLUMN_NAME,METRIC_VALUE)).alias("value")) \
  .writeStream() \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("topic", "output") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "gs://checkpoint") \
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Update()) \
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
  .start();
```

I want to add a extra column  to the result something like this :

```py
.select(to_json(struct( METRIC_COLUMN_NAME,METRIC_VALUE)).add("id_column", "1234")
```

This is contain the static value need to append to all result how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `withColumn` function and provide it with a `literal`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
result
.select(to_json(struct( METRIC_COLUMN_NAME,METRIC_VALUE)).alias("value"))
.withColumn("id_column",lit("1234"))
.writeStream()
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
.option("topic", "output")
.option("checkpointLocation", "gs://checkpoint")
.outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
        .start();
```